# List files in a tarball over internet

Tags: linux, tar

To list an archive's contents I can do :

```
tar -tzvf mytarball.tar.gz
```

But this works for local files only. Can someone point out how to do it (if at all possible) for files over internet.

I tried it with a file

```
wget -q https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.0.tar.gz | tar -tzv
```

But gives

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So does tar work properly with streams for listing ? Are there any compression formats which allow this (without requiring to download the whole file) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your command *would* work, if you told `wget` to output the downloaded file to *stdout* rather than a file:

```
wget -q -O /dev/stdout http://… | tar -tzv
```

However, it *will* require downloading the whole file, at least for Tar and Zip archives. The Zip format puts its "directory" at the very end; meanwhile, Tar does not have a single directory and just has a linear stream of header+data pairs, so filenames are scattered everywhere.

(There certainly should be archive formats that can be listed this way, but I don't know the exact details of any other format out there.)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It is not possible to list the contents of a file over the internet, unless the server has an API or something to process the file and output the results. You should download the file locally and then process the file.

This should work.

```
wget -q https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.0.tar.gz && tar -tzvf git-1.8.0.tar.gz
```

A part from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/

> List the contents of a **tar** file
>
> ```
> $ tar -tvf file.tar
> ```
>
> List the contents of a **tar.gz** file
>
> ```
> $ tar -ztvf file.tar.gz
> ```
>
> List the contents of a **tar.bz2** file
>
> ```
> $ tar -jtvf file.tar.bz2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
wget -qO- https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.0.tar.gz | tar -xvz
```

The file will be downloaded, unpacked, and the screen will show the files.

But if you want make a file Request a and *does not save it*, use:

```
wget -q -O- https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.0.tar.gz | tar -xvz
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between your two command lines? I can’t find any.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you can run shell code on the remote host:

ssh remotehost 'tar -tzvf mytarball.tar.gz'

Comment: This has the benefit of requiring virtually no network transfer aside from the text listing of contents.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect http data output from file to stdout you need to use **-O** switch, then you can grab it

```
wget -q https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.0.tar.gz -O - | tar -tzv
```

But still why you do this? Tar doesn't have file list, so like that you download full file to get file list, and one more time you will need to download full file to get wanted files. So if you plan to get some files from that *tar.gz*, better is to save it and delete it after.

The only good thing about this is to get file list for some *indexing*.
For remote file list *ZIP* files are much better but still you can't download them using wget.